# What has been changed in xml libraries for my code to crash?

Tags: php, xml, xslt, centos8

I started updating an old project.
With centos7 PHP 7 it works, centos8 not so lucky. Could be some changes in the libs?
Still, I need to get it running on centos8.
Also I'm not familiar with xsl.
What could be wrong in the code?
Atm both places with ** throw a warning and program fails.

Warning: XSLTProcessor::transformToXml(): xsl:choose: xsl:when expected first in

```
    **<xsl:template name="D_title"><xsl:choose>**
            <!--<xsl:when test="ver!=''">-->
            <xsl:when test="o='1'"><xsl:value-of select="concat('sometext: ',code)"/></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="concat('sometext (edid: ',edid,')')"/></xsl:otherwise>
            
    </xsl:choose></xsl:template>
```

```
<xsl:template name="login">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name">
            **<form name="logout" method="post">**
            <span><xsl:value-of select="name"/> <input type="submit" class="textBox" name="logout" value="Log out" /></span>
            </form>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <form name="login" method="post">
                    <xsl:if test="error"><span class="error_msg">error!</span></xsl:if>
                    USER: <input type="text" name="username" value="" size="14" maxlength="14" class="textBox" />
                    PW: <input type="password" name="password" size="14" maxlength="14" class="textBox" />
                    <input type="submit" class="textBox" name="login" value="Log in" />
                </form>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Rendering code:

```
        $dom_el = dom_import_simplexml($this->sxe);

        $doc = new DOMDocument('1.0');
        $dom_node = $doc->importNode($dom_el, true);
        $dom_node = $doc->appendChild($dom_node);

        $xslt = new xsltProcessor;
        $xslt->importStyleSheet(DomDocument::load('xsl/template.xsl'));
        return $xslt->transformToXML($doc);
```

Comment: Sorry, can't see anything obviously wrong with your code. Try to investigate which version of libxslt is being invoked to do the XSLT transformation.

Comment: It has libxslt 1.1.32-4.el8, also libxml2 2.9.7-7.el8. Centos7 had libxslt 1.1.28.  I looked into it before, but couldn't make any assumptions.  Also centos8 doesn't offer me previous versions. Funny, [link](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/8.3-systemd/general/libxslt.html) sais libxslt 1.1.32 requires libxml2-2.9.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also stumbled upon the similar issue with libxslt (using libxml 20907, libxslt 10132).  It seems that if there is any whitespaces left in your XSL (.xsl file) between the tags <xsl:choose></xsl:choose> then the error will be thrown.

So remove all whitespaces (including \n) from your xsl:choose element and try again.